# Where exactly can I find the FAA's UAS pilot training course (ALC-451)?

Tags: faa, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, pilot-certification

I'm trying to get my commercial drone operators certificate. I already have a private pilot certificate, so [from the FAA website](https://www.faa.gov/uas/getting_started/fly_for_work_business/becoming_a_pilot/#existing), all I need to do is complete the "Part 107 small Unmanned Aircraft Systems (sUAS) ALC-451" course on [faasafety.gov](https://www.faasafety.gov/), then file some paperwork. But I can't find the course. Is there a direct link to it?

Comment: [The site](https://www.faasafety.gov/) is opening allright, though I'm not exactly sure how its related to aviation as defined in help center.

Comment: The home page is working ... I can't access the actual course page though.

Comment: https://www.faasafety.gov/search/default.aspx?keywords=Part+107+small+Unmanned+Aircraft+Systems+%28sUAS%29+ALC-451&submit=Search

Comment: Looks like its [intermittently working](https://www.faasafety.gov/login/Default.aspx?dest=gslac/ALC/course_content&enroll=true&cID=451). is this the correct course?

Comment: I used the site to get my drone cert on Monday and it was working fine for me (around 10am eastern) as was IACRA

Comment: Yes, that is working! Thank you. I also updated my question to better fit posting guidelines.

Comment: @Arel If the site is working, the question is redundant, isn't it? :)

Comment: I couldn't find the course, so I assume others can't find it either. This post should be helpful to those people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even when faasafety.gov is working without issue, the course can be difficult to find with the site's search feature. The **Part 107 Small Unmanned Aircraft Systems (small UAS)** course is presently available from this direct link: [Part 107 Small UAS Course](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/course_content.aspx?cID=451).

Note that you will have to be logged in to do the course. If you follow that link and are not logged in to [faasafety.gov](http://faasafety.gov), log in and then go to that link again.

Note also that faasafety.gov currently seems to be experienceing occasional technical issues, either due to maintenance or traffic volume. The link may not work reliably at present.